# InApp Provisioning - Apple Pay

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, applepay

I am trying to implement InApp Provisioning - Apple Pay in Xamarin forms project
but I didn't find much resources that explain the steps clearly.
What is the correct setup?
How to test it, and what about env (sandbox or production) ?
Hope that I can find helpful answers
Thank you!

```
var canaddpass = PKAddPaymentPassViewController.CanAddPaymentPass;
if (canaddpass)
{                
    var config = new PKAddPaymentPassRequestConfiguration(PKEncryptionScheme.Ecc_V2);                
    var addPaymentPassVC = new PKAddPaymentPassViewController(config, this);
    View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    Title = "My Custom View Controller";

    var btn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.System);
    btn.Frame = new CGRect(20, 200, 280, 44);
    btn.SetTitle("Click Me", UIControlState.Normal);
    btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
        //this.ShowViewController(addPaymentPassVC, (Foundation.NSObject)sender); This            line will also work
        this.PresentViewControllerAsync(addPaymentPassVC, true);
    };
    View.AddSubview(btn);
}
```

I tried the above code but I got this exception:

> System.Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the type 'PassKit.PKAddPaymentPassViewController': the native 'initWithRequestConfiguration:delegate:' method returned nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PKAddPaymentPassViewController`, which requires the `com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning` entitlement key for your app.

To add this key following steps:

1. Go to *Identifier* section in the [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/):
2. Select your identifier and go to Aditional Capabilities, enable option like this:
   [image]
3. Got to iOS project, add this key to **Entitlements.plist** file:

```xml
<key>com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.developer.pass-type-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)*</string>
</array>`
```

4. On iOS project, go to Properties -> iOS Bundle Signing -> Aditional Resources -> Custom Entitlements:

[image]

> **According [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/ApplePayandPassKitEntitlements/ApplePayandPassKitEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH7-SW4) you need special permission from Apple to submit apps with this key enabled. For more information, contact apple-pay-inquiries@apple.com.**

Comment: i did review for my setup to be match with ones that u wrote it in your comment but still i get the same crash  .... may the code has issue ? @Wilson